# Casting twice in one line

Tags: c, casting

In a project I saw the following line and I did not understand the reason of casting twice.

```
*((MY_STRUCT_T*)(void *)cp->down.common) = *(cp->dpr);
```

What is the reason of casting twice? Why not casting directly to MY_STRUCT_T*?

---

to add more details:

```
typedef union download_s {
    MY_STRUCT_1_T *a1;
    MY_STRUCT_2_T *a2;
    void         *common;
} download_t;

typedef struct cp_s {
 ...
 MY_STRUCT_T *dpr;
 ...
} cp_t;
```

Comment: what is the type of down.common?

Comment: Simply it might be that the coder likes it in this way.

Comment: a colleague suggested it might be necessarry for correct aligning of the data. does it make sense?

Comment: @mustafa: No, it does not make sense that two casts would be used to deal with alignment. Casting is not expected to change the actual pointer value, just change its interpretation. (Casting can change the pointer value in unusual C implementations, but that is almost certainly not what is happening here.) Two casts are more often used to silence compiler warnings; a compiler that warns when you cast a `float *` directly to an `int *` might not warn if you cast first to `void *` and then to `int *`. But that is not what is happening here either, since the type is already `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

If `cp->down.common` is `void *` already casting to the latter (the "inner" cast to `(void *)`) is needless.

This would do the job:

```
*((MY_STRUCT_T *) cp->down.common) = *(cp->dpr);
```

---

A different case would be if `cp->down.common` is declared `intptr_t`, then indeed going via `void *` (as shown in the OP) would be necessary as only `void *` is guaranteed to fit into `intptr_t`.

The C-Standard says:

> [intptr_t] designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to **void** can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to **void**,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there can be any point. Casts in C are rather confusing to many programmers, so you shouldn't take the presence of a cast as an indication that there is a requirement to cast.

There are "too many" (=more than required) parentheses too, it can be written as:

```
*(MY_STRUCT_T *) cp->down.common = *cp->dpr;
```

The right-hand side is fine too, `*` (pointer dereference) has a lower precendence than `->` (element selection through pointer). See the [list of operator precedences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) as always.